# Is there an easy way to convert Flash ActionScript from version 1-3?

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-cs5

Have one. Fla (Flash) file that uses ActionScript 1.0. Need to have it in version 3.0 and was wondering if there is any easy way to convert it? My knowledge of ActionScript is basically nonexistent.

Have access to Adobe Flash CS5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the whole event system changed and it is totally Object Oriented.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion will have to be by hand but there is a 2 to 3 converter in PHP and available here: http://www.5etdemi.com/convert/